# How to solve integration of $\int x(x^2+k^2)^{-1/2} \, dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

As said in title, how do you solve integral $\int x(x^2+k^2)^{-1/2}\,dx$ where $k$ is some constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Euler's substitutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution) solve all integrals of the form $\int R(x,\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c})$, where $R(x,y)$ is a rational function.

In your case $R(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}$ and $a=1$, $b=0$, and $c=k^2$.

Comment: Wow, this is huge overkill, I think...

Comment: @DonAntonio It is 'give a man a fish' vs 'teach a man to fish'.

Comment: Hmmm...not in my opinion and this case, @user144080: someone asking such a basic question most probably is a beginner and would want a basic approach. Yet I think you give him something to thin about. I'm upvoting your answer +1

Comment: @DonAntonio Euler's substitutions are a basic thing. It is more the fault of terrible books lie Stewart's Calculus et allia, that have made trigonometric substitutions more common knowledge than Euler's. There was a time in which Euler's were the first thing you learn.

Comment: Perhaps so, @user. I honestly don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let $u=x^{2}+k^{2}$. Then $du=2xdx$ since $k$ is a constant.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int\frac x{\sqrt{x^2+k^2}}dx=\frac12\int\frac{(x^2+k^2)'}{\sqrt{x^2+k^2}}dx=\frac122\sqrt{x^2+k^2}+C=\sqrt{x^2+k^2}+C$$